# Buggy full screen mode since Flash 18.0.0.204

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, flash

I use Flash Pepper with Firefox via Fresh Player.

The following setup allows me to watch YouTube videos in full screen mode:

- Kubuntu vivid with all the latest updates
- Firefox 39.0
- Flash 18.0.0.194 (Pepper, from Chrome)
- Fresh Player 0.3.1 (from webupd8)
- either the nVidia driver 340.76 or the Nouveau driver from vivid

When I update to Flash 18.0.0.204 or 18.0.0.209 all YouTube videos play in a 2mmx1mm box in the top left corner of my screen.

This can be reproduced with a live USB of Kubuntu vivid.

Does anyone using Flash 18.0.0.194 (Pepper) has the same issue?
Is Chrome/Chromium affected too?
Any idea on how to solve this (beside reverting to Flash 18.0.0.194)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the lower right corner on any YouTube video, click <kbd>About the HTML5 player</kbd> and on the next screen tick the check box so your screen looks like below:

[image]

Then you're not using any flash.  Just HTML5.

I uninstalled Flash a while ago and haven't looked back.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just tried that too. I use paranoid privacy settings in Firefox and all my cache and cookies are deleted when I leave Firefox. Because of that the HTML5 player setting gets lost after each Firefox restart. But fortunately there is a Firefox plug-in for that:  https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/youtube-all-html5/.
Uninstalling Flash is not an option for me; I look a lot of programs from the French-German channel Arte and their webiste only supports Flash.

Comment: Ah, pas de chance alors!  **;-)** Thanks for the acceptance then!  favour returned on your question!

Comment: Who needs flash? =)

Comment: @StéphaneTréboux Since you only mentioned Arte it should be noted that there has been a Totem plugin for some time: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=totem-plugin-arte https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Internet-TV/Stationen#ARTE and also Qarte

Comment: I recently discovered a very nice OSS for viewing German public television programs,  [Mediathekview](http://packages.ubuntu.com/it/xenial/mediathekview).